# Select with priority order

Tags: sql, oracle, select

It's my table, `CAR` :

```
+------+--------+---------+
| id   | model  | color   |
+------+--------+---------+
| 1    | bmw    | blue    |
| 2    | bmw    | red     |
| 3    | bmw    | null    |
| 4    | porsche| null    |
| 5    | porsche| red     |
| 6    | vw     | orange  |
| 7    | car    | null    |
+------+-------+----------+
```

How to select all distincts models with this priority of color :

1. `blue`
2. `red`
3. `null` or other colors...

?

The result of the query would be something like that :

```
+------+--------+
| id   | model  |
+------+--------+
| 1    | bmw    |
| 5    | porsche|
| 6    | vw     |
| 7    | car    |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Show us your current query, and describe what's wrong with it!

Comment: Just mentioning, the names listed are brands, not models. Technically it's OK, but your data model is incorrect, just based on 2 columns you show. Naming should be accurate. Maybe you renamed some things here, but it's confusing to have a bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the row_number() analytic function to set the order of the colours, and then filtering on the row_number = 1:

```
with car as (select 1 id, 'bmw' model, 'blue' colour from dual union all
             select 2 id, 'bmw' model, 'red' colour from dual union all
             select 3 id, 'bmw' model, null colour from dual union all
             select 4 id, 'porsche' model, null colour from dual union all
             select 5 id, 'porsche' model, 'red' colour from dual union all
             select 6 id, 'vw' model, 'orange' colour from dual union all
             select 7 id, 'car' model, null colour from dual union all
             select 8 id, 'vw' model, 'purple' colour from dual)
select id,
       model
from   (select id,
               model,
               colour,
               row_number() over (partition by model 
                                  order by decode(colour, 'blue', 1, 'red', 2, 3), colour) rn
        from   car)
where  rn = 1
order by id;

    ID MODEL  
---------- -------
         1 bmw    
         5 porsche
         6 vw     
         7 car
```